# Can we bound $\sum_{i=1}^ke^{-{\rm i}2\pi\langle\omega,\:x_i\rangle}$ by $\sum_{i=1}^ke^{-{\rm i}2\pi\langle\omega,\:x_i\rangle}\hat g(a_i\omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in[0,1)^d$, $a_1,\ldots,a_d>0$ and $$f(\omega):=\sum_{i=1}^ke^{-{\rm i}2\pi\langle\omega,\:x_i\rangle}\hat g(a_i\omega)\;\;\;\text{for }\omega\in\mathbb R^d,$$ where $g(x)=e^{-(x/\sigma)^2}$ for some $\sigma>0$.

Suppose $|f(\omega)|<\varepsilon$ for all $\omega\in\mathbb R^d$ with $0<\|\omega\|<\delta$. Can we show that $\left|\sum_{i=1}^ke^{-{\rm i}2\pi\langle\omega,\:x_i\rangle}\right|$ is also bounded by something multiplied by $\varepsilon$? This is clearly true when all $a_i$ are equal to the same value, since we can then pull the $\hat\varphi$ out.

Comment: How is it possible that $|f(\omega)| < \epsilon$?  I am wondering because when you take $\omega \to 0$, $f(\omega) \to k$

Comment: @Youem Note that I only say that $|f(\omega)|<\varepsilon$ for all $\omega\ne0$ with $\|\omega\|<\delta$.

Comment: Yes but by continuity you can take the limit when $\omega$ goes to $0$

Comment: Well, yes. But note that I didn't say what $\varepsilon$ is. For example, if $\varepsilon\ge k$, I guess you wouldn't see a problem. Maybe I should have phreased the question differently. The important thing I'm trying to achieve is bounding $\left|\sum_{i=1}^ke^{-{\rm i}2\pi\langle\omega,\:x_i\rangle}\right|$ by some factor times $|f(\omega)|$.

Comment: Yes I think you should rephrase the question because if you want the last term to be smaller than $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ is already bigger than $k$ the result is trivial.